# Какой падеж использовать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, управление, причастия

*...противодействия разного рода фобиям, намеренно распространяемым в обществах порочными силами.*
Подскажите, *распространяемым* или *распространяемых*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашлось полное [предложение](https://muslim.ru/articles/283/26524/).

> По словам Рушана Аббясова, на данной авторитетной площадке при участии лидеров авраамических религий прозвучали призывы к углублению и расширению сотрудничества с умеренными и созидательными силами в мире во имя торжества справедливости, сотрудничества в социальной и гуманитарной, и что особенно важно, в образовательной сферах между людьми вне зависимости от их конфессиональной и религиозной принадлежности, **противодействия разного рода фобиям, намеренно распространяемых в обществах порочными силами.**

В словаре Ожегова:
[противодействие](http://www.endic.ru/ozhegov/Protivodejstvie-27927.html), -я, ср. Действие, препятствующее другому действию. Оказать противодействие кому-нибудь, чему-нибудь. Действие равно противодействию.

Противодействия (чему? Д. п.) фобиям — управление;
**фобиям** (каким?) **распространяемым** (причастие) — согласование.

В таком внушительном предложении немудрено запутаться с падежами. Правильно — распространяемым фобиям.